# How can I apply `smerge-refine` for all conflicts by default using `smerge`?

Tags: smerge

I am using `smerge` to resolve conflicts in my git repo.

I use `C-c ^ n` to jump to the next conflict. When I view the conflict, for all, I want to apply `smerge-refine` automatically.

Workflow should be: `C-c ^ n` and `C-c ^ R` , where I want `C-c ^ R` to be triggered automatically.

```
R   smerge-refine     Highlight the words of the conflict that are different.
```

Where is it possible to apply `smerge-refine` right for the all conflicts by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set or customize `diff-refine` to a non-nil value then `smerge-refine` is applied "automatically" in `smerge-next`.

See the [doc string of `diff-refine`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/dec958258b133b4c21224c594da433919d852800/lisp/vc/diff-mode.el#L102-L108) for the valid values:

> If non-nil, enable hunk refinement.
> The value `font-lock` means to refine during font-lock.
> The value `navigation` means to refine each hunk as you visit it
> with `diff-hunk-next` or `diff-hunk-prev`.
> You can always manually refine a hunk with `diff-refine-hunk`.

This answer is valid for Emacs 27.1 and higher.

Comment: Like `(setq diff-refine t)` ?

Comment: @alper I've added the doc string for `diff-refine`. `smerge-next` does not really care about the actual value it just checks that it is non-nil. Nevertheless, you should use one of the proposed options to make `diff-mode` work like expected.

Comment: So can I do something like: `(setq diff-refine 'navigation)` ?

Comment: @alper Yes, that is possible in your init file. But, you can also just customize and save the customization. With small things like that I do it that way.